# Visit Local Server on Mobile Device Keep Getting Apache Default Page

Tags: apache

I am trying to access localhost server run on my Ubuntu 14.04 from iPhone and Android within same wifi network.

I use http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx to access the localhost. But on both of them I can only get Apache "It Works" default page but on my desktop the website works fine.

Here are some config I use:

System ubuntu14.04

Apache 2.4.7

and apache2.conf:

```
<Directory /path/to/my/webapp/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    #Require all granted
    Require local
    Require ip xx.xx.xx
</Directory>
```

The path to my app is not under /var/www

and ports.conf:
    Listen 80

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443  
</IfModule>
```

Is there anything wrong in my config which prevents my mobile device access localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it by set the 000-default.conf in sites-available folder pointing to my target web application path.
Problem solved.